# Why my cat uses paws to bring food from plate to floor and then eats it from floor?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, eating, play

My cat doesn't like to eat from plate. She rather likes to eat from floor.

In case of large food such as a piece of fish she will kick the food on plate a few times. Then she grabs the piece with mouth and puts it down on floor. Then she will go on kicking, eating some, kicking again, and so on. In this process she will make the whole floor dirty.

In case of solid food like tuna flavored whiskas, she will use her paws to bring one of the tiny pieces to floor. Then she will play football with it. Then she eats it. In this process lots of pieces remain lying here and there and the costly food is wasted. Moreover there is problem of red ants over here who takes full advantage of food lying here and there.

So why my cat does this? Is there any way to teach her not to do this?

She has lots of toys to play with. It is not that she doesn't get to play.

Comment: See https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/how-can-i-persuade-our-maine-coon-to-be-less-messy-with-food or https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/why-do-my-cats-play-soccer-with-their-dry-food-on-the-floor

Comment: Also see https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/why-does-my-cat-prefer-eating-on-the-carpet